# preg_replace which uses the return value of function as replacement

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following code:

```
$message = preg_replace($pattern, "$this->get_bitly_url('$0')", $message);

function get_bitly_url($url) {
    // do stuff to get the url

    return $newurl;
}
```

I would like to replace the matches with the return value of the function `get_bitly_url()` in the same class.

But I got the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: MyClass::$get_bitly_url in /path/to/MyClass.php on line 43
```

So I changed to preg_replace with:

```
$message = preg_replace($pattern, "self::get_bitly_url('$0')", $message);
```

This works, but I would like to know whether this is the right way to do it.

So... is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, definitely not :). Use preg_replace_callback: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes, otherwise PHP tries to evaluate `$this->` too early:

```
$message = preg_replace($pattern, '$this->get_bitly_url("$0")',
```

You need to pass a string *containing* an expression to `preg_replace` here. But if it's in double quotes it gets evaluated ***as*** string expression *before* it becomes a function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using PHP5.3 or more, you can use this :

```
$myObject = $this;
$message = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) use($myObject) {
    return $myObject->get_bitly_url($matches[0]);
}, $message);
```

With previous version, you can define the function somewhere else and pass the function name as a string to preg_replace_callback, but this is slower.